# md5deep utility giving wrong/different output!

Tags: linux, encryption, hashsum, cryptography

md5deep utility gives different result when calculating hashes. I have used several online tools to calculate hash and they give same result but md5sum or md5deep program on linux gives different output. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
Website        = http://hash.online-convert.com/whirlpool-generator 
string         = foobar
whirlpool hash = 9923afaec3a86f865bb231a588f453f84e8151a2deb4109aebc6de4284be5bebcff4fab82a7e51d920237340a043736e9d13bab196006dcca0fe65314d68eab9

Website        = http://www.sha1-online.com/
string         = foobar
whirlpool hash = 9923afaec3a86f865bb231a588f453f84e8151a2deb4109aebc6de4284be5bebcff4fab82a7e51d920237340a043736e9d13bab196006dcca0fe65314d68eab9

md5deep tool on Linux Mint x64 KDE i5 processor
string = foobar
whirlpool = 37b100ba4d775e394c6db6062e2ca0cc8431948f7aea03c0a07991bcd139599735bdcac9dc0b4ae3c91912f93dd0f736a8c0c7a44996c2bd2e16939ac37c44a7
```

Answer (score 6):

I bet you are using `echo foobar`: this will add a new line at the end of the word, changing the hash to what you get. The proper way is:

```
$ printf foobar | whirlpooldeep
9923afaec3a86f865bb231a588f453f84e8151a2deb4109aebc6de4284be5bebcff4fab82a7e51d920237340a043736e9d13bab196006dcca0fe65314d68eab9
```

Using `echo` (or `vim` without the binary mode `-b` enabled, as you seem to do in your test) returns the hash you get:

```
$ echo foobar | whirlpooldeep
37b100ba4d775e394c6db6062e2ca0cc8431948f7aea03c0a07991bcd139599735bdcac9dc0b4ae3c91912f93dd0f736a8c0c7a44996c2bd2e16939ac37c44a7
```

Comment: I was actually storing "foobar" in a.txt. This I did using vim to ensure no newline was created. `$ whirlpooldeep a.txt`. Why is this giving different output?

Comment: Because vim adds a new line ;)

Comment: In fact I'm showing the data provided as input to the different programs is not the same.

Comment: Ohwait. Too early for me to be posting. You proved that md5deep ẃorks the same with intended input. Duh.  You might also provide output with the newline to demonstrate for OP how that output looks.

Comment: @atk: seems logic: added wrong example.